# Welcome Screen does not pop up when booting from USB - just a purple screen. Where is the problem?

Tags: boot, usb

I encounter problems since last update in 16.04 (damaged kernel, does not boot). Tried to remove the latest version, but terminal does not allow this, so I decided to install again.

Downloaded the 16.04 version and the 17.04 version and copied these to USB. Szstem does not boot, though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you literally copied them or made a bootable USB drive?